# Simple (?) inequality with complex numbers and absolute value

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, absolute-value

I am trying to prove the following:
$$ \left| \frac{z^{2n}}{2+z^n+ z^{5n} } \right| \leq \frac{|z|^{2n}}{2\left| 1 - |z| \right| } $$
whenever $|z|<1$. Moreover, I am invited to use the following:
$$ ||z|-|w|| \leq |z-w| \leq |z|+|w| $$

Comment: If $|z|<1$ then $|z|^{5n} \le |z|^n <1$. $|2+z^n+z^{5n}| \ge 2-|z|^n -|z|^{5n} \ge 2-2|z|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever $|z|<1$, we have that higher powers of $z$ are smaller, i.e., $|z^m| < |z|$ for $m>1$. Thus
\begin{align*}
\Big|\frac{z^{2n}}{2+z^n+z^{5n}}\Big| &= \frac{|z|^{2n}}{|2+z^n+z^{5n}|}\\[5pt]
 &\leqslant \frac{|z|^{2n}}{||2|-|z^n+z^{5n}||}\\[5pt]
 &\leqslant \frac{|z|^{2n}}{|2-|z+z||}\\[5pt]
 &= \frac{|z|^{2n}}{2|1-|z||},
\end{align*}
as required.